# Get Data from Mysql using (PHP) and send it to typescript/javascript using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, typescript

I have got data from mysql in php, and i want to send it to typescript using JSON. but when load the php page. nothing showed in the screen. It always shows a blank page.

```
$select  ="SELECT * from `filiere`";
$run = mysqli_query($connect, $select);
$temp = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($run)) {
    $temp[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($temp);
```

from the code, it should show the data in json format.

what it is the problem?

Comment: did you try print_json()?

Comment: i tried print_json($temp); but it gives me Call to undefined function print_json()

Comment: *blank page* means something is(or might be) broken. Add these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: does your query work?

Comment: The content for json_encode must be UTF-8 encoded. Test it with var_dump or print_r.

Comment: @inarilo yeah, 100%.

Comment: @DanielO.when i use var_dump($temp); it gives me the result

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, an unexpeted blank page usually means some kind of error + error reporting turned off.

Try to turn error reporting on

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**EDIT #1:**
Based on the comments, it seems that `json_encode()` fails, so returns `false` (echoing `false` will result in a blank page).

The `json_last_error()` and/or `json_last_error_msg()` functions should be used to find the error.

**EDIT #2:**
The first argument of `json_encode()` must hold only UTF-8 encoded strings.

Comment: Try `var_dump(json_encode($temp));` If this also does not print out anything, your php script is not executed correctly.

Comment: it prints 'boolean false', so?

Comment: That means `json_encode()` fails. Use `json_last_error()` or `json_last_error_msg()` to see what the error is.

Comment: it prints 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'

Comment: Try setting the encoding for the communication with mysqli using `mysqli_set_charset("utf8")` (right after `mysqli_connect`).

Answer (score 0):

I think i've understood where is my error. 
You are all right. i have some data with frensh letters like ('é', 'ù'..). I think that was the problem.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

did you set endpoint content-type on php ?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```